# Prove that $\,f(z) \equiv 0,\,$ if $\,f(z)\,$ is entire

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $f(z)$ be an entire analytic function, such that
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\lvert\, f(re^{i\theta}) \rvert\,d\theta\le r^{16/5}, \quad 
\text{for all}\,\,\, r>0
$$
Show that

$$f(z)\equiv 0.$$

Thank you for you help.

Maybe we need to use Cauchy Theorem.

Comment: What can you say about the coefficients of the taylor series of $f?$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Cauchy Integral Formula, for $r\to 0$, we obtain that $f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=0$. Thus $f(z)=z^3g(z)$, where $g$ is also entire, and we get for $g$ that
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \lvert g(r\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta})\rvert\,d\vartheta\le r^{1/5}, \quad r>0.
$$
Now, for every $z\in\mathbb C$, let $r>2\lvert z\rvert$, and according to Cauchy Integral Formula
$$
g(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|w|=r}\frac{g(w)\,dw}{w-z},
$$
and hence
$$
\lvert g(z)\rvert \le \frac{1}{2\pi}\max_{|w|=r}\lvert  w-z\rvert^{-1}\int_0^{2\pi}\lvert g(r\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta})\rvert \,d\vartheta\le \frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot \frac{2}{r}\cdot r^{1/5}
=\frac{1}{\pi r^{4/5}}\to 0,
$$
as $r\to \infty$.

Thus $g\equiv 0$, and so is $f$.

Comment: Nice! +1. Thank you